# Shopify API to get All Records for Customers,Orders & Products (Django)

Tags: django, shopify

I have searched for getting all customer one by one.But after some study understand the whole way to solve.
for getting 250 data from shopify api we can use limit but pagination and synchronization for getting all data we need some step to get all data.

```
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@%s.myshopify.com/admin/api/%s/" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, SHOP_NAME, API_VERSION)
endpoint = 'customers.json?limit=250&fields=id,email&since_id=0'
r = requests.get(shop_url + endpoint)
```

Step 1:Where we need to put the initial id to start extraction and store to your db

`customers.json??limit=250&fields=id,email&since_id=0`

Step 2:Next changes the since_id value with with last id of your extraction like my image.
last id=5103249850543 (suppose)
[Mentioned in Fields Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFZeH.png)

`customers.json??limit=250&fields=COLUMN_YOUNEED_FOR_CHK&since_id=5103249850543`

Comment: Based on the docs,  Shopify will give you the [`link for the next page`](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/pagination-rest) in a paginated request, and can be found in the header of the response. You probably want to use that instead of `since_id`

Comment: Thanks for your comments.Following my way i have extract all the data using the api.